# OOB Document Set not finding control templates on migrated site

Tags: migration, path, managed-path

I have a site that was migrated to a new farm using Backup-SPSite / Restore-SPSite.

In the new farm, document sets are not loading and are throwing file not found errors for some of the control templates.

There is a custom content type that is based on document set and was created on the old farm. Looking at the `documentsethomepage.aspx` file for that content type in designer, I can see that the paths to the control templates are `/sites/sitename/_controltemplates/templatename.ascx`.

These are obviously missing the `/15/` part of the path.

However, as a test, we created a new document library, and added the OOB document set content type to it, and created a test instance of a document set, and it also is not working.  Looking at *it's* `documentsethomepage.aspx` file in designer, the paths to the control templates are `/sites/sitename/_controltemplates/15/templatename.ascx`, which looks more correct, but we're still getting file not found errors.

And, as another test, we have a test site set up that was not migrated from the other farm.  We added the OOB document set content type to a library in that site, and it works.  In the `documentsethomepage.aspx` file there, the paths are just `/_controltemplates/15/templatename.ascx`.

So.... what's going on here?  Why are there server relative paths to the control templates in the site that was migrated?

Additional info - on the old farm, the site was at the root of the web application (i.e. just `http://server-name/`) and in the new farm it is using a managed path (`http://server-name/sites/sitename`).

Is there a setting on the SPSite or root web object that needs to get changed to reflect that it is using a managed path now and no longer at the root of the web app?